# Display the summation of all numbers reference to specific condition

Tags: sorting, sum, ksh, aix, uniq

I am having an input as follows:

Input:

```
FILE1    3   5   
FILE2    5   9   
FILE3    4   6   
FILE1    3   5   
FILE1    4   6   
FILE1    3   5   
FILE2    4   6   
FILE3    3   5   
FILE1    8   3   
FILE5    3   5
```

The needed output should be as follows:

Output:

```
Name(count)    COLUMN1     COLUMN2   
FILE1(5)       21          24
FILE2(2)       9           15
FILE3(2)       7           11
FILE5(1)       3           5
```

Output needed explanation:

- Count each occurrence of each name in column 1 in input then to print the name once in output with (COUNT)
- Get the summation of column 1 in input for each name and display the summation in output informnt of its name.
- The 3rd column should be the summation as well as the 2nd column above.

More explanation:

- The output displays FILE1 with count of 5 as FILE1 repeated 5 times in input.
- FILE1 with count 5 has both values of 21 and 24
- 21 came from the summation of any FILE1 column 2 in input
- 24 came from the summation of any FILE1 column 3 in input

I tried many sort with uniq and for/while but couldn't get the needed output.

- I don't need to use many temp files to get what is needed, I need simple on-liner command(s)

Comment: folks, any update on this please?

Comment: The best solution would be using `awk`. Is an `awk` solution allowed? I am curious where you got stuck in the while-loop: not the best for performance but not to complicated: `while read -r name c1 c2; do .. done < input`. Are the columns separated with tabs or spaces?

Comment: awk is fine on this os, however i couldn't get a proper syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk you only need to parse all lines once:

```
awk '{col1[$1]+=$2; col2[$1]+=$3; names[$1]+=1} 
     END { for (name in names) 
            { 
              printf ("%s(%s) %s %s\n", name, names[name], col1[name], col2[name]);  
            }
         }' inputfile
```

EDIT
Explanation:
awk processes the input line by line. From each line the name `$1` is used.
The summation is done with `col1` and `col2`. Any new entry will start with 0, so I can just add the value in the current line. The first column is counted `+=1`, others are summed.
I could have added:

```
printf ("Processing %s, col1 subtotal=%s, col2 subtotal=%s\n",
        $1, col1[$1], col2[$1]);
```

This can be helpful when your inputfile behaves unexpected.
In the END block I go through all names stored and use them to show the corresponding column totals.

Comment: Walter, it worked just perfect , however when I tried to test it on the real file  I have here I had problems, can I have some explanation ...?